# mprotect() like functionality within Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, mprotect

I am in a Linux kernel module, and I allocate some memory with, say, `vmalloc()`.  I want to make the memory have read, write, and execute permission.  What is the clean and appropriate way of doing that?  Basically, this is generally the equivalent of calling `mprotect()`, but in kernel space.

If I do the page walk, `pgd_offset()`, `pud_offset()`, `pmd_offset()`, `pte_offset_map()`, and then `pte_mkwrite()`, I run into linking errors when I tried it on 2.6.39.  Also, it seems that if I am doing the page walk, it is a hack, and there ought to be a cleaner and more appropriate method.

My kernel module will be a loadable module, so internal symbols are not available to me.

Thanks, in advance, for your guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good answer to this question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450557/is-there-any-function-analogous-to-mprotect-in-the-linux-kernel.

```
asm-generic/set_memory.h:int set_memory_ro(unsigned long addr, int numpages);
asm-generic/set_memory.h:int set_memory_rw(unsigned long addr, int numpages);
asm-generic/set_memory.h:int set_memory_x(unsigned long addr, int numpages);
asm-generic/set_memory.h:int set_memory_nx(unsigned long addr, int numpages);
```

they are defined here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.3/source/arch/x86/include/asm/cacheflush.h#L47

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by invoking do_mprotect() [kernel function corresponding to mprotect()] directly ?

Comment: `__do_sysmprotect` is a static function. Not sure if it can be called in modules.